# Сумма цифр большого факториала без использования BigInt JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

/*
Cумма цифр в числе 10! равна 3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 = 27.

Найдите сумму цифр в числе N!  (N < 1000)
Определите функцию sumOfFact(n), которая получает n
и возвращает искомую сумму.
Поскольку большие числа не могут быть представлены в JS точно,
разряды большого целого числа сохраняйте в массиве.
Не использовать BigInt.
*/

```
const factorial = n => n ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1;


function sumOfFact(n) {
 let num = String(factorial(n))
 if(n >= 22) {
 return num.split('').map(function(e){return parseInt(e)}).reduce(function(a,b){return a+b});
 } else {
     
 }
}
```

Код считает вплоть до n <= 22,
подскажите, что сделать дальше

Comment: *поскольку большие числа не могут быть представлены в JS точно, разряды большого целого числа сохраняйте в массиве* вы решили эту часть задачи проигнорировать, или что? Вам явно написали, что вычислить не получится, делайте иначе.

Comment: А зачем условие про 22? Где оно в задаче?

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin мои наблюдения)

Comment: число в массив распишите, и умножайте вручную по разрядам

Comment: Не отказал себе в удовольствии и [набросал быстрое решение](https://jsfiddle.net/Denisdude/2tcfs793/). Правда очень рекомендую решить задачу самостоятельно, ведь она не так сложна, как кажется. Ответ не пишу, т.к. лень всё подробно расписывать. Всё, что вам нужно - это реализовать поразрядное умножение.

Answer (score 2):

Число представим в виде массива цифр от младших разрядов к старшим. Умножение школьное в столбик (функция `scale`). Факториал он и в Африке факториал. В конце суммируем цифры. Решение не самое быстрое (сложность `N^2`), но простое.

```
const scale = (n, f) => {
    let carry = 0;
    let j = 0;
    while (carry > 0 || j < n.length) {
        const p = carry + ((j < n.length) ? f * n[j] : 0);
        n[j] = p % 10;
        carry = Math.floor(p / 10); 
        j += 1;
    }
};

const factorial = n => {
    const f = [1];
    for (let i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        scale(f, i);
    }
    return f;
};

const sumOfFact = n => factorial(n).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

P.S. Подумайте что будет если константу `10` в `scale` заменить на `100`?

Comment: Красивое решение! :) Правда при `f > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` пойдут ошибки (ненужное округление). Но обычному человеку такие значения никогда не понадобятся.

Comment: По формуле Стирлинга при `f > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` надо будет отвести под факториал массив длинной более `1.3 * 10^17` элементов. Столько памяти нет ни у кого. Да и алгоритм квадратичный, память превратится в пыль раньше чем мы сосчитаем факториал.

Comment: Само собой :) Просто я имею вредную привычку рассматривать каждую функцию по-отдельности и стараться находить максимально универсальное решение. В данном случае `scale()` идеально вписывается в решение задачи, однако применять её отдельно для перемножения огромных целых чисел будет проблематично. НО в данном случае это и не нужно :)